# How to get a control on eclipse workspace or project through java program

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am stuck with opening an eclipse  project using java program.

**Program:**

```
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    System.out.println("Root path: "+root.getFullPath().toString());
```

**Result:**

Root path: /

**Aim:**

My project is located at suppose path : C:/User/XYX/workspace/project2

Step 1: I want to open this workspace

Step 2: A particular project within the workspace - say project2

Step 3: Refresh the project

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is this a Eclipse plugin? You cannot use the Eclipse APIs in a normal Java program. You must use a plugin or write an Eclipse headless application.

Comment: Yes it is a plugin application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the root folder, all you need to do is : Run menu -> Run Configurations -> Main (tab) -> Workspace Data : Location -> Change it to Workspace Folder you want

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc of IResource](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html), the path of the workspace root is always `/`, because the path is relative to the workspace.

So it seems you are going in the good direction. Have you then tried to open a project and refresh it with for example:

```
root.getProjects()[0].refreshLocal()
```

Or open the project by its name:

```
root.getProject("project2").refreshLocal()
```

Comment: I tried:

 IProject[] projectList = root.getProjects();
 System.out.println("Total projects: "+projectList.length);

Result:

Total projects: 0

:( :( :(

Comment: Are you doing this from a plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

`getFullPath()` gives the location relative to the workspace root so this is always `/` for the root itself. `getLocation()` gives the path in the file system.

In a plugin or Eclipse headless application the workspace is automatically opened.

Get a project with

```
IProject project = root.getProject("project2");
```

and refresh it with

```
project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, progressMonitor);
```

Comment: I tried below:-

                workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

  root = workspace.getRoot();

  System.out.println("Root path: "+root.getLocation());


  
  project = root.getProject(path+projectName);

  System.out.println("Project path: "+project.getLocation());

  project.refreshLocal(project.PROJECT, null);




At line: project = root.getProject(path+projectName);


I encountered exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path for project must have only one segment.

The root path returned was like:  C:/User/XYX/junit-workspace

Comment: `getProject` takes the project name only - no path. The first parameter of `refreshLocal` is a depth - project.PROJECT is not appropriate.

Comment: As per your suggestion I removed path from getProject() and changed 1st param of refreshLocal() to IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE and now Project path is returned as null.


I have doubt: If root path is  C:/User/XYX/junit-workspace and the project on which I want to operate is at C:/User/XYX/workspace location then passing only project name as project2 will not resulting in searching for project2 in junit-workspace???

If it is doing so then we need to change the default root path. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You must specify a project in the current workspace, you cannot work on a project in a different workspace.

Comment: The workspace in use is fixed during Eclipse startup and cannot be changed without restarting Eclipse. You could write a separate Eclipse headless application to access the second workspace and use `Runtime.exec` or similar to run it.